# How to read GridView ItemTemplate data (XAML/C#) on Click Handler

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am using `GridView`. I needed to disable click on few `itemTemplate`. I have a property `IsClickable` set to false and I want to read this property inside ItemTemplate click event handler.

```
    void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var isClickable = e.ClickedItem;
    }
```

This e.ClickedItem shows as follows when I debug:

[image: Debug inspection of clicked item]

See in the image, `IsClickable: false`. Is there a way to check this property and do `return false;` inside my click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cast the `ClickedItem` object to its specific type, something like this:

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var isClickable = ((MyItemType)e).ClickedItem;
    //...
}
```

Where `MyItemType` is the type of the clicked control (or a base class / interface of theirs that has an `.IsClickable` property).

If you set a watch on the `e.ClickedItem` object, you will see its type in the Watch panel during debugging.

Edit:

You can't quite do `return false;` in the event handler, since its return type is void.